# Timeout while Internet Explorer busy

Tags: watin

I'm using WatiN automation tool. I've a popup window in which i need to enter values in somefields and click on submit button upon which the value is inserted in the main page. I'm able to insert the value into tht fields and click on the submit button but, after this the execution stops and i get the error "Timeout while Internet Explorer busy". so please help me to handle this.

thankingyou

Answer (score 2):

You might try using:

```
button.ClickNoWait()
```

rather than:

```
button.Click()
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfect for me: Disable Protected Mode (in the Internet Security Proprties, un-check the "Enable Protected Mode" checkbox right under the security level slider. I'm using IE7, and I reproduced the issue once I switched the Protected mode back on.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of this blogpost I wrote, http://www.teknologika.com/blog/modal-dialogs-and-dropdowns-in-watin/.

It explains about modal popups in a lot of detail